# Applying QgsExpression to item of layout legend using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, print-composer

I am using a print composer from QGIS using python. Inside a QGIS project (`.qgz`, QGIS version 3.18.3), I created a print composer layout called "mylayout" and added a map and a legend. I would like to apply a `QgsExpression` with python to the "Soil cover" item of the legend (see image).

**Expression I want to apply** (Automatic wrap text (line break) in map composer legend)

```
wordwrap(@symbol_label, 30)
```

**Current legend (left collapsed, right expanded)**

[image]

**Code**

I created a`QgsExpression` and a `QgsExpressionContext` linked to the legend but I have no clue of what to do next.

```
# sample of init code 
manager = project_instance.layoutManager() # get layout manager from Qgis project
layout = manager.layoutByName("mylayout") # get existing layout in layout manager

# define expression and expression context
legend = layout.itemById("legend") # get legend from layout
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False) # not sure about this one
exp = QgsExpression("wordwrap(@symbol_label, 30)") 
context = legend.createExpressionContext()

# I tried
exp.evaluate(context)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code snippet below:

```py
map_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Soil cover')[0]
manager = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager()
layout = manager.layoutByName("Test Layout")
legend = layout.itemById("legend")
layer_node = legend.model().rootGroup().findLayer(map_layer)
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(True)
layer_node.setLabelExpression('wordwrap(@symbol_label, 30)')
layout.refresh()
```

You can see the results on my test layer and layout below (I used the expression `'wordwrap(@symbol_label, 10)'`)

[image]